# Error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityManager" while deploying .EAR on glassfish

Tags: jpa, glassfish

currently I am facing a problem in deploying .ear file on glassfish 4. 
This has a JPA application and I am using an EJB startup session module to test it.
When I deploy this application on local glassfish server, I get following error.

"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityManager".

I have made sure that I included all the required libraries to classpath. Can anyone help me identify what is the problem?

Below is the complete error log:

```
2013-11-05T15:08:31.330-0500] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=32 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1383682111330] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2013-11-05T15:08:31.500-0500] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=32 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1383682111500] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2013-11-05T15:08:31.505-0500] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [global] [tid: _ThreadID=32 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1383682111505] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Class [ javax/persistence/EntityManager ] not found. Error while loading [ class edu.stevens.cs548.clinic.domain.PatientDAO ]]]

[2013-11-05T15:08:31.505-0500] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [global] [tid: _ThreadID=32 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1383682111505] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Class [ javax/persistence/EntityManager ] not found. Error while loading [ class edu.stevens.cs548.clinic.domain.ProviderDAO ]]]

[2013-11-05T15:08:31.594-0500] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/users/ganu/ec2/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/eclipseApps/Clinic/lib/ClinicDomain_1.jar/_ClinicDomain_1] [tid: _ThreadID=32 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1383682111594] [levelValue: 800] [[
  EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b]]

[2013-11-05T15:08:31.601-0500] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/users/ganu/ec2/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/eclipseApps/Clinic/lib/ClinicDomain_1.jar/_ClinicDomain_1.connection] [tid: _ThreadID=32 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1383682111601] [levelValue: 800] [[
  file:/users/ganu/ec2/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/eclipseApps/Clinic/lib/ClinicDomain_1.jar/_ClinicDomain_1 login successful]]

[2013-11-05T15:08:31.605-0500] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.default] [tid: _ThreadID=32 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1383682111605] [levelValue: 900] [[
  The collection of metamodel types is empty. Model classes may not have been found during entity search for Java SE and some Java EE container managed persistence units.  Please verify that your entity classes are referenced in persistence.xml using either <class> elements or a global <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> element]]

[2013-11-05T15:08:31.606-0500] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.org.glassfish.persistence.org.glassfish.persistence.common] [tid: _ThreadID=32 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1383682111606] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Cannot create tables for application Clinic. The expected DDL file default_ClinicDomain_1_createDDL.jdbc is not available.]]

[2013-11-05T15:08:31.614-0500] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [ejb.portable_jndi_names] [javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers] [tid: _ThreadID=32 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1383682111614] [levelValue: 800] [[
  EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB Test: [java:global/Clinic/ClinicTest/Test!edu.stevens.cs548.clinic.test.Test, java:global/Clinic/ClinicTest/Test]]]

[2013-11-05T15:08:31.836-0500] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [edu.stevens.cs548.clinic.test.Test] [tid: _ThreadID=32 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1383682111836] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Initializing the user database.#######]]

[2013-11-05T15:08:31.837-0500] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [edu.stevens.cs548.clinic.test.Test] [tid: _ThreadID=32 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1383682111837] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Creating provider enrtity.######]]

[2013-11-05T15:08:31.837-0500] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [edu.stevens.cs548.clinic.test.Test] [tid: _ThreadID=32 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1383682111837] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Created provider enrtity.######]]

[2013-11-05T15:08:31.839-0500] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=32 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1383682111839] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication start method
javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton Test
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer$SingletonContextFactory.create(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.instantiateSingletonInstance(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:396)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.doStartup(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:158)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.start(EjbApplication.java:166)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:497)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: javax.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton Test
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.createSingletonEJB(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:483)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.access$000(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:81)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer$SingletonContextFactory.create(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:654)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityManager
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.proceed(CallbackInvocationContext.java:209)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:986)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.proceed(CallbackInvocationContext.java:205)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.init(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:986)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:412)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:375)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:1949)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.createSingletonEJB(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:475)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityManager
    at edu.stevens.cs548.clinic.domain.ProviderDAO.addProvider(ProviderDAO.java:72)
    at edu.stevens.cs548.clinic.test.Test.init(Test.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.BeanCallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:1035)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.proceed(CallbackInvocationContext.java:205)
    ... 64 more
```

Comment: Have you tried this http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-javax-persistence-entity/

Answer (score 5):

Get the javaee.jar file and include it in your project classpath.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api

Or

you can directly download from the below link

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaeeapi70jar.htm

The javax.persistence.Entity is a class inside the J2EE SDK library “javaee.jar“, you are missing this jar file in your project class-path.